# Regex to match a sentence end with full stop(.) ignore decimal point

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to match a sentence stating with specific word and end with full stop. A sentence could contain a decimal number.

Example

This is closely followed by Indora where 2,194 motorists were fined. **South, East, West and North zones of city traffic police have booked 1,514, 983 and 594.00 motorists respectively.** Interestingly, the biggest chunk of motorists booked was from MIDC area where 2,297 were penalized for using shrill horns.

I want to match the line in bold
If i use the regex below

```
south[^\.]*\.
```

It will match

**South, East, West and North zones of city traffic police have booked 1,514, 983 and 594.**

How can I ignore decimal number from a sentence to match a sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a look-ahead constraint to allow a digit after the dot:

```
South(?:[^\.]|\.(?=\d))*\.
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pM3zL8/1)